# How can I import firebase analytics using webpack bundler without getting error?

Tags: javascript, webpack, firebase-analytics

I have a application that imports firebase analytics and uses webpack to build js.

I have an error after clearing cache and deleting `node_modules` (I had another error).

So, after doing this, the error started to appear:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'firebase/analytics' in 'src'
Did you mean 'index.esm.js'?
BREAKING CHANGE: The request 'firebase/analytics' failed to resolve only because it was resolved as fully specified
(probably because the origin is strict EcmaScript Module, e. g. a module with javascript mimetype, a '*.mjs' file, or a '*.js' file where the package.json contains '"type": "module"').
The extension in the request is mandatory for it to be fully specified.
Add the extension to the request.
resolve 'firebase/analytics' in 'src'
  Parsed request is a module
  using description file: package.json (relative path: ./src)
    Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
      looking for modules in node_modules
        existing directory node_modules\firebase
          using description file: node_modules\firebase\package.json (relative path: .)
            using description file: node_modules\firebase\analytics\package.json (relative path: ./dist)
              Field 'browser' doesn't contain a valid alias configuration
        ...
```

I have tried to replace this with `require`, I tried using `firebase/analytics/dist`, `firebase/analytics/dist/index.esm.js`.
It does not work as well

My imports in `index.js` is:

```js
import initializeApp from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics, logEvent } from "firebase/analytics";
```

Comment: Have you try "Add the extension to the request."?

Answer (score 0):

Its ridiculous how Google can release a package like this.

To help Webpack resolve the path you must go to `node_modules/firebase/analytics/package.json` and change

`"dist/index.cjs.js": "dist/esm/index.esm.js"`

to

`"dist/index.cjs.js": "./dist/esm/index.esm.js"`

In my case I updated the value under `browser`, if you work on a react-native project you should update the one under `react-native`.